# Calculating missing partial currents and resistances

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have the following task:

The circuit shown is given. The total current \$I\$ and all partial currents \$I_{1}\$ to \$I_{6}\$ as well as the voltages at the resistors \$R_{1}\$ to \$R_{6}\$ are to be calculated.

[image]

The voltage \$U_{s}\$ is \$24 \mathrm{~V}\$.
The resistors have the following values:
\$ R_{1}=4 \Omega, R_{2}=8 \Omega, R_{3}=3 \Omega, R_{4}=7 \Omega, R_{5}=10 \Omega, R_{6}=2 \Omega, R_{}=20 \Omega, R_{8}=20 \Omega\$.

I now get around to calculating the total voltage and current. I can also still calculate the voltage at resistor one and five and the partial current four. However, I don't see how I can continue with the given quantities to determine the remaining missing quantities. I would be very grateful if I could have a tip here.

I have calculated:

\$ R_{all}= 29 \Omega\$

\$I_{all}=\frac{24}{29} A\$

\$U_{R1}=\frac{96}{29} V\$

\$U_{R5}=\frac{600}{29} V\$

\$I_4=\frac{60}{29} A\$

Comment: Mark everything you have calculated already to the circuit, and you'll hopefully notice what you can calculate, since you have total current and total voltage.

Comment: write the resistor values on the schematic - that may help you to see simplifications.  Do series and parallel resistor calculations as appropriate - for example, determine the effective resistance of the R3 R4 R5 block.  Also, show your calculations - how did you get Rall = 29 Ohms?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic approach:

1. Look at the information you have. If you know the voltage across or
   current through a resistor, use Ohm's Law to find any missing value.
2. Use KVL around any loops. If you have an equation with just one
   unknown, solve for it.
3. Use KCL at all nodes. If you have an equation with just one unknown,
   solve for it.

Repeat this process until you have found all desired values. There is no magic bullet. You simply have to put in the effort to solve the problem.

As you work, mark the schematic with all of the values that you know. This will help you see opportunities to easily calculate more information.

Comment: Thank you both (answer and comments) for your tips, that helped to see the circuit more structured.